# ipad: UINavigationController Inside a ModalView not pushing views

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I have a UINavigationController with a UIViewcontroller containing a tableview that is being presented as a UIModalPresentationFormSheet on the ipad. Which works fine until I try to push another view on top of it. Nothing happens anyone else have this issue?

It also works perfectly on the iphone. and the didselectrowatindexpath is not a branched method.

Nick

Comment: I'm getting the same problem ,no idea how to solve it. Exactly the same code runs in another screen just fine, and this used to work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I knew what I did but I somehow fixed this, all I can say is that it is possible.

Comment: I am having the same issue with SwiftUI, i realized that the navigationView works different on iPad than it does on iPhone, that's why it works perfect on iPhone but does nothing on iPad